# Angular2 how to direct to a lazy loaded module?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I got the following structure:

```
+--AppModule
|  +--OverviewModule
|  |  +--OtherModule1
|  |  +--OtherModule2
|  |  +--OtherModule3
```

To load OverviewModule I use lazy-loading. This is my AppModule route config:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'overview',
        loadChildren: 'app/injus/views/overview.module#OverviewModule'
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'overview',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        component: PageNotFoundComponent
    }
];
```

When the path is `'overview'` it displays my overview module. When the path is `''` I want it to go to 'overview'. Unfortunately this won't work.

Overview routing:

```
export const overviewRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: OverviewComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: 'othermodule1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'othermodule1',
                loadChildren: 'app/injus/views/othermodule1/othermodule1.module#otherModule1'
            },
            {
                path: 'othermodule2',
                loadChildren: 'app/injus/views/othermodule2/othermodule2.module#2otherModule1'
            },
            {
                path: 'othermodule3',
                loadChildren: 'app/injus/views/othermodule2/othermodule3.module#3otherModule1'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

How can I direct to a lazy loaded module?

Comment: Do you have a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the OverviewComponent?

Comment: Yes I do have a router-outlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the cause of my problem. I was importing the OtherModules in my AppModule which resulted in the OtherModule being loaded for the path `''`.

Answer (score 0):

## Please try it it should work:

*Main problem in* **export const overviewRoutes : Routes = []**

```
export const overviewRoutes: Routes = [
     {
        path: '',
        component: OverviewComponent,
    },
    {
        path: '',
        component: OverviewComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'othermodule1',
                loadChildren: 'app/injus/views/othermodule1/othermodule1.module#otherModule1'
            },
            {
                path: 'othermodule2',
                loadChildren: 'app/injus/views/othermodule2/othermodule2.module#2otherModule1'
            },
            {
                path: 'othermodule3',
                loadChildren: 'app/injus/views/othermodule2/othermodule3.module#3otherModule1'
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

## Add

```
Routes = [ 
     {
        path: '',
        component: OverviewComponent,
      }
    ....
   ]
```

## Remove

```
children: [{
       path: '',
       redirectTo: 'othermodule1',
       pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    ....
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration seems to be correct...

I created a Plnkr for you: [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/61UHcl5DWT6pmXE7gmaN?p=preview)

Try to check paths to modules and the `<router-outlet>` position in your templates
(You need a `<router-outlet>` in the AppComponent template and another in OverviewComponent)